# How to check if posts are waiting a Review

Tags: support, review-queues

I recently noticed a "Review" link on the menu bar on SO, but in the review page there are 0 posts to review. How can I tell when posts are waiting to be reviewed? Is there a notification alert? Or will I simply have to check it now and again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just reached 500 rep - congratulations! You can now review First Posts and Late Answers.

There is no alert for when there is stuff to be reviewed for those queues - you just have to check it manually. (I try to stalk the review queues on Judaism.SE, because there is no alert, and it's so much harder to get review badges on small sites. :))

When you reach 2k, you'll be able to review suggested edits as well, and for those, there is a counter in the top bar, next to review:

[image]

Comment: Should this be made a feature request?

Comment: You can ask a new question as a feature request, but search for a duplicate first - i have a feeling one exists.

Comment: @Harry I am virtually certain it was asked before.... and the reason it performance.  Those queues move too quickly to put a notification in the top-bar.  First, it will be outdated by the time you clicked on it anyway.  And second, that number for suggested edits is cached (server side), so to make it update more frequently, you will impact performance of the site.  And even if it updated more frequently to update for the other queues, it would still not be worth it because of my first point (it would be outdated).

Comment: I can definitely see that these ques move fast, so I guess it would make sense not to have a feature like this. thanks @psubsee2003